# Meaning of "such of them as [...]"

Tags: meaning

I've come across the following expression:

> Europe is a sleepy place. And **such of our men as do not** manage to emigrate to the Tropics are tired and sleepy along with it.
>
> (*I, Robot*, Isaac Asimov)

I have never encountered this before and am having trouble parsing it. It seems like an archaic form meaning more or less "those among our men who do not manage [...]".

Is there more to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You interpretation is correct, and it means what you think it means.

However, you can rephrase it in a way that keeps the wording identical except for only changing two words:

> *such* → *those*
> *as* → *who*.
>
> Europe is a sleepy place. And **those** of our men **who** do not manage to emigrate to the Tropics are tired and sleepy along with it.

Comment: Thanks, this confirms what I thought!